# Synchronous Messaging Queue

Tags: apache-kafka, rabbitmq, publish-subscribe, producer-consumer

Can there be a scenario wherein one can use the synchronous Pub-Sub model to build a system? Generally, they are used to achieve asynchronous behavior wherein the producer publishes messages on the queue and gets an acknowledgment and once the consumer consumes the message and processes it. Does anybody like Kafka, Rabbit-MQ provide this use case.

Comment: Can you be more specific than "build a system"?

Comment: I just wanted to know can there be any scenario or has someone even encountered using a synchronous pub sub model in any of their usecase. I just kept a question like that. It is more of an hypothetical question. Building a system could be anything like building whatsapp, twitter, netflix etc.